# Start browser on chromium os at system startup

Tags: raspberry-pi, chromium, google-chrome-os

I am trying to start the browser and have it load a certain page when the system starts, but I have not yet been able to find a solution.

I am using [Chromiun OS on a raspberry PI 4](https://github.com/FydeOS/chromium_os-raspberry_pi).

Does anyone have any idea how to achieve this?